# trying to find all prereqs for courses in prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog

Have been stuck on a problem for hours and I really need help at this point.

The goal is to create a predicate **all_prereqs(C, L)** that returns a list of all the direct and in-direct pre-requisites of the course.  We are given a series of courses linked to a list of their prerequisites.

```
prereqs(cse115, []).
prereqs(cse116, [cse115]).
prereqs(cse191, [cse115]).
prereqs(cse241, [cse116,cse191]).
prereqs(cse250, [cse116,cse191]).
prereqs(cse305, [cse250]).
prereqs(cse321, [cse341]).
prereqs(cse331, [cse250,mth142]).
prereqs(cse341, [cse241]).
prereqs(cse379, [cse241]).
prereqs(cse380, [cse241]).
prereqs(cse396, [cse250]).
prereqs(cse411, [cse241]).
prereqs(cse421, [cse305]).
prereqs(cse422, [cse421]).
prereqs(cse431, [cse331]).
prereqs(cse435, [cse250,mth309]).
```

I understand that there should be a helper class and I tried something like

```
prereq1(C1,C2):- prereqs(C1,L),prereq1(member(C2,L),C3).
```

It returns a 'no' of course. 
I have written down on paper what must be done to these values, but my inexperience with Prolog has impeded me from doing it.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

OK thank you for that information.  At one point I did have that idea but had no idea how to terminate recursion when the list was empty.

```
prereq1(C1,C2):-prereqs(C1,L),member(T,L),prereq1(T,C3). prereq1(C1,C2):-T\==[].
```

This just returns true, I am having trouble understanding the termination of the recursive call when prereq list is empty.

Comment: Please share your pseudo-code (what you have written on paper)! It would help a lot with the exact answer. And add it to the question, don't do it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

You're writing your code in *functional* data model, but Prolog has instead a *relational* data model. Then your rule should be

```
prereq1(C1,C2) :- prereqs(C1,L),member(C2,L),prereq1(C2,C3).
```

but that cannot succeed either, because the recursive call will always fail when hit a course with *empty* prerequisites list. Note, the initial part is ok:

```
prereq2(C1,C2) :- prereqs(C1,L), member(C2,L).
```

giving all *immediate* prerequisites, then we should just add a closure for each of these immediate, by means of recursion.

```
prereq2(C1,C2) :- prereqs(C1,L), member(T,L), ...
```

please complete by yourself, and you'll get

```
?- prereq2(cse331, L).
L = cse250 ;
L = mth142 ;
L = cse116 ;
L = cse191 ;
L = cse115 ;
L = cse115 ;
false.
```

Note the duplicate. Prolog has a idiomatic way to handle this:

```
?- setof(C, prereq2(cse331, C), L).
L = [cse115, cse116, cse191, cse250, mth142].
```

*edit* your Prolog should warn you about a singleton in your rule:

```
prereq1(C1,C2):-prereqs(C1,L),member(T,L),prereq1(T,C3).
```

`C3` must become `C2`. With that you should have completed your task. Termination will be handled 'implicitly' when member will be given the empty list - this will happen multiple times in the example I've given.